# encrypt using php and decrypt using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have encrypt string from php and want to render it on client side but I dont know how to mix it using javascript

```
$enc = encrypt_url('a');
echo "My enc result = ".$enc."<br>";
echo "My dec result = ".decrypt_url($enc);
```

[image]

I've pass it using ajax  so, client side retrive it as "ZEJxSkpkYjhhNWUvenZkdFlUSGxvUT09"

I'm trying to decrypt but cannot

```
<script>
.....
success: function(result) {
    var x = `<?php decrypt_url('\\`+ result+`\\') ?>`;
    console.log(x)
} 
</script>
```

but the results is null
[image]

Comment: why didn't you return the decoded string in result from server-side?

Comment: and missed `echo` before `decrypt_url`

Comment: `\`<?php decrypt_url('\\\`+ result+\`\\') ?>\`;\`` you can't call a PHP function from javascript

Comment: @Gulshan Because, that is uniqe ID so, people cannot see the real ID from my db. sorry my bad, but still null even i give echo.

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino is `PHP` code called in `.js` or `.php` file?

Comment: because you're currently confused on client side programming and server side, you're loading in the javascript variable into the PHP function which is not possible since PHP runs first, so basically you'll get no value in the `decrypt_url()`

Comment: @Gulshan I'm working for php. I just put <script></script> inside php file.

Comment: what you can do to decrypt is make an xmlhttprequest or what you call AJAX

Comment: @Kevin t that time I had seen that js and php could be combined using the separator "\\" but I forgot where the reference was.

Comment: Your x var in JS code will get value of decripted string '\\`+ result+`\\', literally. When function is called that row: var x = ... will already be printed. Check page source to see what do you get for that JS.

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino I think you are misinformed thinking that double backslash will magically combine PHP and JS codes using that. using double backslashes are used to escape the single backslash

Comment: @MilanG `<?php echo decrypt_url('\`+ result +`\\') ?>` the results still null, no error just null same as my picture above

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino `console.log(result)` and post it here. Lets see what you have in `result` first

Comment: Actually there is no php funciton decrypt_url() ?! Is that your function?

Comment: @MilanG yes decrypt_url() is my helper in codeigniter i got reference from this website https://luqman.web.id/meng-enkripsi-url-di-codeigniter/ . for php this working fine, I just can't to decrypt using js

Comment: i feel the context of this is that the OP is trying to hide the value that's coming from PHP that's why JS needs to decrypt it, but the problem is the decrypt function is also in PHP side, thus the reason behind invoking your PHP function inside the success block, if I assessed it correctly, what you should do and have is that you should also have a counterpart decrypt function in JS as well that matches the algorithm with the library in PHP

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino check my updated answer

Comment: `the results still null` you can't call a PHP function from javascript

Comment: you should have used something like this: both have encrypt and decrypt on both sides (PHP / JS) https://gist.github.com/ve3/0f77228b174cf92a638d81fddb17189d

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Ajax for this:

## encrypt.php

```
$encrypt = encrypt_url('a');
```

## decrypt.php

```
die(json_encode(decrypt_url($_POST['encrypted_string'])));
```

## Script

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "decrypt.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {'encrypted_string': <?=$encrypt?>},
        success: function (response) {
           alert(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: 1. I using ajax to get data from my controller
2. I have to send encrypt string from my controller to my views.
3. succes: function (result) is my data what I get from my controller
4. the data that I get is in the form of encryption
5. I want to decrypt the data I received earlier

Comment: You should create the variable that you're going to pass through into your ajax request. Then you should use Ajax to decrypt it and use it in your JS script as displayed in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
.....
success: function(result) {
    var x = `<?php decrypt_url('\\`+ result+`\\') ?>`;
    console.log(x)
} 
</script>
```

When PHP returns this page it will execute the `decrypt_url` function on the string ``` '\\``+ result+``\\' ``` since you **can not** pass a parameter from JavaScript to PHP like that. Therefore your `x` will become either nothing (i.e. `null`) or something random (depending on the `decrypt_url` function). Use AJAX to pass parameters from JavaScript to PHP.

A simple test case to show what happens:
test.php:

```
<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
                <script>
                        function(result)
                        {
                                var x = '<?php echo decrypt_url('+result+',true) ?>';
                                console.log(x)
                        }
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

That will be rendered by the browser as:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function(result)
            {
                    var x = '
```

As you can see the output starting from the `<?php` tag is broken.

Some of you might wonder why, so I thought I should extend my answer a bit. First of all this is a logical mistake because the OP makes the assumption that PHP could be controlled from the client-side. I can see that because the piece of code quoted is HTML with embedded PHP where a PHP block itself sits in a piece of JavaScript. Now let's have a look at what happens during execution with a simplified version of the OP's code:

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function test(result)
      {
        var x = `<?php strtoupper('\\`+ result+`\\') ?>`;
        console.log(x)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let's save that code as `test.php` and have a look at what PHP makes of it when the file is executed: first of all it basically transform everything to a single PHP script (this is a simplification of the actual process to show the basic principle). After this step your code will look like this:

```php
echo "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Test</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<script>\nfunction test(result)\n{\nvar x = `";
strtoupper('\\`+ result+`\\')
echo "`;\nconsole.log(x)\n}\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

Those who looked closely will probably have spotted the first issue: there is no semicolon after the `strtolower(...)` call. So let's assume it's there and look at what the line will return when interpreted by PHP:

```
'\\`+ result+`\\'
```

I'm pretty sure that is not the input the `decrypt_url` function of the OP needs. But let's see how the code looks now (with the missing semicolon added):

```php
echo "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Test</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<script>\nfunction test(result)\n{\nvar x = `";
'\\`+ result+`\\';
echo "`;\nconsole.log(x)\n}\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

Now we are missing another `echo`, without one the second line will cause an error. So let's fix that:

```php
echo "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Test</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<script>\nfunction test(result)\n{\nvar x = `";
echo '\\`+ result+`\\';
echo "`;\nconsole.log(x)\n}\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

So, after fixing the missing semicolon and the missing echo we get valid PHP code - let's see how the output will look like:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function test(result)
{
var x = `\\`+ result+`\\`;
console.log(x)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point PHP sends the output to the client. Since I used the `strtolower` function there is no change here that breaks the code, the only thing the `test` function will do is to wrap the `result` in double-backslashes, but if I had used `strtoupper` the `test` function would fail because `RESULT` is undefined. I imagine that the `decrypt_url` function is not supposed to just wrap the input in back-slashes but it will transform the input in a more complex way, which will most likely completely break the resulting code so that the page can't be loaded.

I hope this makes a bit clearer why this approach can not work.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` add this in `php` on the top of `test.php`

Comment: let see why its broken

Comment: did you have `decrypt_url()` function in your `test.php`?

Comment: It's broken because the PHP tag is broken up with apostrophes.

Comment: Try `var x = '<?php echo "'+result+'") ?>';` instead and you get the same issue, it does not matter what you put in there, it is simply invalid syntax.